# Upload file não esta seguindo o codigo

Tags: php, javascript

Quando eu faço upload de um arquivo, primeiro ele faz a barra de progresso com o JS, e depois ele move o arquivo que foi feito upload para a pasta. O problema é que ele ignora o `echo 'começo'` e o `echo 'final'`, e eu gostaria de fazer um teste ali, algo como:

```
$name = $_POST['nameSendTorrent']; 
if(empty($name)){echo 'Precisa colocar um nome'; return;}
```

E nesse caso ele também ignora caso seja feito upload de um arquivo, e eu gostaria de poder "controlar" o momento em que o arquivo é feito upload, e não quando aperta o submit do form.

Codigo:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(function() 
{
    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');

    $('form').ajaxForm(
    {
        beforeSend: function() {
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
        {
            document.getElementById("progressBarCurrent").style.display = 'block';
            var total_perc = total | 0;
            var current_perc = position | 0;
            document.getElementById("progbar").innerHTML = Math.floor((current_perc / (total_perc / 100)) * 100) / 100 + '%';
            document.getElementById("progbar").style.width = current_perc / (total_perc / 100) + '%';
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            status.html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}); 
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="formSendTorrent"  id="formSendTorrent" name="formSendTorrent">
        <div class="defaultStyleSend fontDefault" id="defaultStyleSend">
            <a>Nome:</a> 
            <input type="text" class="nameSendTorrent" name="nameSendTorrent">
        </div> 
        <div class="defaultStyleSend fontDefault">
            <input type="file" multiple name="inputfileSendTorrent[]" id="inputfileSendTorrent"> 
        </div>
        <div id="progressBarCurrent">
            <div id="progbar"></div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" name="submitSendTorrent" class="submitSendTorrent" value="Enviar">
    </form>

<?php
require DIR_FUNCS.'funcSQL.php';
require_once DIR_FUNCS.'Torrent.php';

if(isset($_POST['submitSendTorrent']))
{   
    echo 'começo';

    $i = 0;

    $uploaddir = DIR_ARQUIVOS.$chave.'/';

    foreach ($_FILES["inputfileSendTorrent"]["error"] as $key => $error) 
    {
        $arqName = $_FILES['inputfileSendTorrent']['name'][$i];
        $arqTemp = $_FILES['inputfileSendTorrent']['tmp_name'][$i];

        if(!@move_uploaded_file($arqTemp, $uploaddir.$arqName))
        {
            $error = error_get_last();
            echo $error['message'];
        }

        echo '1';

        $i++;
    }

    echo 'final';
} 
?>
```